# Alpine Linux startup script

Tags: system-installation, startup, live-usb, alpine-linux

I have a USB flash drive, which boots Alpine Linux into RAM memory.

**I wish to run a script directly after startup (login to WIFI, etc.). Is that possible?**

It is advised to place a startup script in `/etc/local.d/UpdateIssue.start`, but my USB flash drive does not contain the folder `/etc`. Simply having the script after boot in the filesystem would be enough, then I manually execute the file. However, all I see is this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that to answer to this question, there are several points that needs to be clarified.

**1. Why there's no  `/etc` dir in my USB?**

Because the USB content you see is what is needed to allow Alpine to boot. If you download an ISO file [1], you are not going to find any `/etc` dir as well.
The `/etc` dir will appear when the USB starts, when the filesystem is uncompressed and loaded in memory.

**2. Yes, but I need the `/etc` dir to run my cool script, where can I find it?**

The filesystem resides, compressed, into `boot/initramfs-lts`[2].

You can open it and take a look inside[3], but that's not the way you can accomplish your goal.

**3. Ok, gotcha. But now, can you answer my question?**

Proceed as follow:

- Boot your PC with that USB (I assume you have a bootable USB with Alpine Linux Image, if not, look at [4] )
- Run `setup-alpine` and follow the installation guide. Alpine has three different disk modes[5], here we assume you would choose diskless
- Now, it's time to create your `/etc/local.d/UpdateIssue.start`. Don't forget to make it executable with `chmod +x /etc/local.d/UpdateIssue.start`, and to add local service to start on boot: `rc-update add local`
- Save what you have done with `lbu commit`

This last step is **MANDATORY** if you are going to use diskless mode. In this way, Alpine will create a file named `$hostname.apkovl.tar.gz` in your USB key [6].

At the next reboot, when Alpine found this overlay file, will unpack it and restore the saved state.

[1] https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/releases/x86_64/alpine-standard-3.15.4-x86_64.iso

[2] If you are using  the ISO mentioned on [1]

[3] https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-uncompress-and-list-an-initramfs-content-on-linux

[4] https://docs.alpinelinux.org/user-handbook/0.1a/Installing/medium.html#_using_the_image

[5] https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Installation#Installation_Overview

[6] https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_local_backup